“Cmd” key does not bring up Windows start menu, in Macally Ultra Slim USB wired keyboard
I purchased a Macally Ultra Slim USB wired keyboard. It was working fine until recently the Cmd won’t bring up the start menu in Windows 11.
On some websites that has a video embedded in it, with the keyboard plugged in, it would endlessly fast forward the video. When I try to click the middle mouse button, Windows was supposed to bring up the scroll icon (see below), but with the keyboard plugged in, the scroll icon immediately goes away. I'm not able to scroll.



These problems have been persisting for 3 months. I've tried this keyboard on a different computer, and I get the same issues. I don't think there will be a driver update for this.
These issues are really nuisance when using this keyboard. The keyboard's been purchased for more than 6 months, but this problem emerged 3 months ago. So I can't return it.
Is there anything I can do other than throw away the keyboard?

That sounds like either hardware damage has occurred to the keyboard and/or keyboard's firmware and/or driver (if it has a non-generic driver) has been corrupted
